# DOM elements are only sporadically created despite being loaded by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, dom

This is a very specific problem and one that makes me particularly confused. The project in short: I'm working on a counseling website that gets data from an API and is loaded with AJAX. I'm now trying to get old, archived chats to be be preloaded and displayed with css on click in a menu.

Here's the problem: It works... but only about 1 in 3 times or after reload of the page. I don't understand how that can be, either it should work or it doesn't.
I checked and the data is always loaded (it has to because the current chat is opened first and always works)
So how can that be?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/vsbt/counselling/archive/',
    data: {},
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log('ajax /vsbt/counselling/archive/');
    console.log(data);

    //menu is created
    $('#counselling_status').append('<ul class="archivedCounsellings"></ul>');
    $('.archivedCounsellings').append('<h2>Archivierte Chats</h2>')

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        //menu items are added
        var that = data[i].messages[0].title;
        $('.archivedCounsellings').append('<li class="' + that + '"><a>' + that + '</a></li>')
        $('#vbst_communication_container').prepend($('<div class="counselling inactive ' + that + '" />')
            .append($('<h2>' + that + '<h2>')));

        //the messages are added with to classes for styling
        data[i].messages.forEach(function(message) {
            $("div." + that)
                .append($('<div />')
                    .addClass(message.type)
                    .append($('<p />')
                        .text(message.message)))
        });
        //this doesn't work either, you can maybe tell me why, but that's not the issue
        $('.counselling').data("status", [i]);
    }

    $(".archivedCounsellings").append('<li class="aktuell"><a><br>Zur aktuellen Beratung</a></li>');

    //click event to toggle the displayed counseling
    $('.archivedCounsellings li').click(function() {
        $('.counselling').addClass('inactive');
        $('div .' + $(this).attr('class')).removeClass('inactive');

        //workaround which works, but isn't really acceptable
        // no load workaround
        // if($('.openCounselling').siblings().length == 0){
        //     window.location.reload();
        // }

        // $('.statusDisplay').text($('#job_status_' + $(this).attr('class')).data("status"));
        // console.log($('div .' + $(this).attr('data-status')));
    });
```

PS. I'm aware of the typo in 'counselling'
PPS. if you find a mistake that obviously makes it fail that probably happend while copying since, remember, it does work sometimes.

Comment: When it doesn't work have you checked the console for errors? Or at least verified the return state of the request?

Comment: how are you triggering this ajax?

Comment: _yes, no console errors what so ever
_it's triggered when the user is logged in, simultaneously to the current chat, which as I said, always works but the archived one sometimes, despite getting data, doesn't create any dom elements

Answer (score 1):

Ok so if anyone ever encounters this problem: I was just explained AJAX a little bit closer and basically AJAX sends out all the requests more or less simultaneously. Whatever happens in the done function happens after that, hence the successful data request.
What I did, was initiate the container for said elements in a different function. So occasionally that one was a little bit slower and there was no place to append my elements to --> no error, just nothing happened.
It's unlikely that anyone will see this, since it's very specific, but maybe this'll help someone, at least i know better now